# Diferença semântica de "Malloc" e Calloc"

Tags: c, c++, malloc

Estava na aula de programação com `C` e me surgiu a dúvida sobre a diferença entre `Malloc` e `Calloc`, mas não no que cada uma faz, mas no significado do "M" e do "C".

Sei que `Malloc` vem de `memory allocation`, já o `Calloc` eu não faço ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Se você der uma pesquisada, vai encontrar que não existe uma resposta certa para o caso do calloc. O "m" do malloc vem de memory allocation. Já o "c" do calloc é uma questão dividida.

Segundo este livro [Linux System Programming](https://books.google.gr/books?id=LOeK6EZfiH0C&pg=PT467&lpg=PT467&dq=c%20calloc%20etymology&source=bl&ots=HbimNHQqE2&sig=cSfiuKSnEww_Rsjw8NNgHxzL3ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBmoVChMIvumwq5-YxwIVgaEUCh3qKwBa#v=onepage&q=c%20calloc%20etymology&f=false) não existe nenhuma fonte oficial que define o significado do calloc.

Mas a título de curiosidade algumas pessoas acreditam que o "c" vem da palavra em ingles *clear* que significa limpar. Isso se deve porque o calloc garante que o pedaço de memória retornado vem limpo e inicializado com o valor zero.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: muito obrigado ajudou muito, era essa a questao mesmo que estavamos dicutindo

Comment: Ótimo, lembra de aceitar a questão como correta :)

Comment: @FelipePorto a resposta do Gabriel resolveu seu problema? É a melhor disponível? Se sim, recomendo você marcar a questão como aceita. Você pode mudar de ideia sobre a resposta aceita em qualquer momento também, caso surja uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 1):

O nome `calloc()` certamente é uma abreviação de *clear-allocation*, equanto `malloc()` vem de *memory-allocation*.

Porém, as funções de alocação dinâmica da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h` possuem comportamentos diferentes:

1. `calloc()` inicializa a memória alocada com "zeros";
2. `malloc()` não inicializa a memória alocada.

Segue uma possível implementação de `calloc()`, que basicamente é a combinação das funções `malloc()` e `memset()`:

```
void * calloc( size_t nmemb, size_t size )
{
    size_t len = size * nmemb;
    void * p = malloc( len );
    memset( p, 0, len );
    return p;
}
```